# Xamarin Forms ListView does not update correctly

Tags: c#, android, listview, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

I'm working with Xamarin Forms and MVVMLight.

So I'm displaing a List of "Patients" with a ListView. Each Element of the ListView has a Delete-Button. When clicked the Patient is deleted from the List and the View is notified with RaisePropertyChanged().

The Problem now is that when I add multiple Patients and then want to delete one. Always the last one is removed in the View. I debugged the App and saw that the right one is delted from my List. But when the View updates its data, always the last Entry is removed.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}" HasUnevenRows="true" x:Name="Patientlist">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="Patient" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}"/>
                                    <Label Text="Benötigte Proben"/>
                                    <Label Text="Untersuchungen"/>
                                    <Button Text="Bearbeiten" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding PatientID}"/>
                                    <Label Text="Test"/>
                                    <Label Text="Test"/>
                                    <Button Text="Löschen" Command="{Binding DelCMD}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>  
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

So this is my ListView. The Button "Löschen" ist the delete-Button. It executes the following Command:

```
private RelayCommand delCMD;

    public RelayCommand DelCMD
    {
        get
        {
            return delCMD ?? (delCMD = new RelayCommand (()=>Messenger.Default.Send<PatientM> (this, "delPat")));
        }
    }
```

This code is in my PatientModel-Class. And sends a Message to the VM where the Element is removed.

```
        public void delPatient(PatientM Patient)
    {
        Patients.Remove (Patient);
        RaisePropertyChanged ("Patientlist");
    }
```

This code is then executed in the VM. An well like I said the right Patient is removed from the List (Patients.Remove). But after RaisePropertyChanged is called the wrong is Element is delted in the View. Always the last one even tough I deleted another on in the List.

Comment: What is typeof(Patients)? If it's an ObservableCollection, then it should raise CollectionChanged by itself correct? I think with that RaisePropertyChanged, that is saying that the entire list has been swapped out.

Comment: To reload data on ListViews in X.Forms with MVVMLight, I ran into a similar issue and ended up setting the datasource to null and then back to the datasource. So something like:
// update data source
// dataSource = null (this is the Observable Collection)
// dataSource = updatedDataSorce